# Echo PHP inside BigCommerce HTML href (self-referencing hreflang tags)

Tags: php, html, bigcommerce, hreflang

I'm trying to use PHP to echo the full URL of the current page as the href value.

I read a few different post and came up with the following code, which isn't working:

`<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" hreflang="en-us" />`

I'm in the templates > layout > base.html file

Comment: It works for me.  In what way is this code failing?  What is the resulting output?

Comment: Maybe try the other way around, echo the <html> tag in a php echo?

Comment: hmm... maybe because I'm using it on BigCommerce and it's outputting the PHP code as text. My first time using BigCommerce. I tried the other way around as well but no luck.

Comment: I think Big Commerce is an important point in this question, and probably should be added. :-)

Comment: You're right, thanks. Added it to the question

Comment: @DerekColeman Add it as a _tag_.  Make sure to also be more specific on where this code is.

Comment: Just added it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

As BigCommerce is a closed-source SaaS platform, you can't run your own arbitrary PHP on the backend. Customization must be done by the template helpers made available by the platform, or using the public APIs. Here's a few links that might help:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/global-objects-and-properties

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/handlebars-helpers-reference

For your use case then, this might look like:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="{{settings.secure_base_url}}{{settings.request.absolute_path}}" hreflang="en-us" />
```

Comment: Thanks for that. So it looks like there is no single variable to get the url from all the page types. They seem to be doing it with the canonical in head.meta_tags but I can't access that either

Comment: If you simply wish to get the current URL of the page, you can consider `{{settings.request.host}}` or `{{setings.secure_base_url}}` + `{{settings.request.absolute_path}}`

Comment: You can just use JS and get the fully qualified URL by using `window.location` - apply that programatically as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://{{settings.request.host}}{{settings.request.absolute_path}}?setCurrencyId=1" hreflang="en-gb" />
```